# How to apply CSS style while printing?

Tags: java, css, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I am using GWT/GXT.

i have used GWT's grid and each row is highighted in background color using CSS. but applied css is not printed in printed page. how can i print with css?

I am calling Print functionality as below:

```
Print.it("<link rel='StyleSheet' type='text/css' media='paper' href='mainApplication.css'>", DOM.getElementById("myId"));
```

in **mainApplication.css** i placed style as below:

```
@media print {
    print_background {
    background-color: #EBECE4 !important;
    }
  }
```

is my CSS style correct? Please help me.

in the code :

i created a horizontal panel and added GWT grid to it as below.

```
HorizontalPanel recordsPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

//GWT grid is created and the same is added to recordsPanel 
recordsPanel .add(grid).
```

i applied css style for grid rows as below:

```
recordsGrid.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, "print_results_background");
```

Now i want to print the records with css style.

Thanks!

Comment: The stylename specified in css file is "print_background" & the stylename applied to the RowFormatter is "print_results_background". Why is it so? Is this a typo or you really have done this mistake in your code?

Comment: What is "myId"? How did you assign it to your grid?

Answer (score 1):

You CSS style isn't correct for a trivial issue: lack of dot (.) before print_background class. Correct code is:

```
@media print {
     .print_background {
           background-color: #EBECE4 !important;
     }
}
```

Comment: But the dot lacks in `@media print { ... }` block.

Comment: try with # as probably its an id

Answer (score 1):

`paper` is not a valid value for the `media` attribute. Correct your `link` tag as follows:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='print' href='mainApplication.css' />
```

*Ignoring other syntactic mistakes as mentioned by other posters, please refer to RAS's comment on the question also (regarding the differing class name).*

#### Reference

- [Media Types on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing in the css to specify if print_background its an id # or a class .